# Writing Variable Text-Name to file via shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Very simple question with a complicated solution that I haven't been able to find online. Maybe I am wording my questions wrong in google.

Its very simple I want to add to my .bash_profile file exporting a new directory to my $PATH via shell script. Something like this:

```
echo "export /usr/local/slope-stability/bin:'$PATH'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

However I want the $PATH to be written as $PATH not as the actual content the variable contains. Right now when I execute this I get

```
export /usr/local/slope-stability/bin:
```

written to my file along with all the content of my current $PATH as well.

Anyway I can just actually add the text $PATH instead of the content?

Answer (score 2):

You can just escape the `$` character:

```
echo "export /usr/local/slope-stability/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: or "terminate" the dbl-quoting, and just have single-quoting for `'$PATH'`, i.e. `echo "export /usr/local/slope-stability/bin:"'$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile` . Good luck to all.